# Disassociate an Apple ID from a computer

Tags: imac, security, apple-id

There's a work computer (iMac) I'll soon stop using, which might be used by other people in the future.

While I've mainly used a separate work-only Apple ID on the computer, I suspect I may have used my personal Apple ID on the computer from time to time.

I want to make sure that my personal Apple ID isn't used in the future on the work computer. How do I ensure this is the case?

Answer (score 4):

Go to System Preferences, and check "iCloud" and "Internet Accounts". Sign out where necessary, and once neither of them list your personal account, you're good to go.

You may also want to make sure your web browsers don't remember any of your passwords.

Comment: this doesn't seem to remove all traces of the apple id. For instance, the next user who tries to sign in sees your AppleId by default, and certain apps like FaceTime appear to retain info (like recent calls) even though you are logged out.

Answer (score 3):

**Removing an associated device or computer from an Apple ID**

To remove a device or computer from your Apple ID:

1. Open iTunes.
2. Sign in to your Apple ID by choosing **Store** > **Sign In** from the **iTunes** menu.
3. Choose **Store** > **View My Account** from the iTunes menu.
4. From the Account Information screen, click **Manage Devices**.
5. Click the **Remove** button next to the device name you would like to unassociate.

**Note**: Removing a device from your Apple ID does not override the 90-day timer. You must wait 90 days from the day the device was first associated with your Apple ID before it can be associated with another Apple ID.

Source: [iTunes Store: Associating a device or computer to your Apple ID](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4627)